# Perl Array of regular expressions -- matching elements of an array

Tags: arrays, regex, string, perl

I am trying to match and remove elements from an array called `@array`. The elements to be removed must match the patterns stored inside an array called `@del_pattern`

```
my @del_pattern = ('input', 'output', 'wire', 'reg', '\b;\b', '\b,\b');

my @array = (['input', 'port_a', ','],
             ['output', '[31:0]', 'port_b,', 'port_c', ',']);
```

To remove the patterns contained in `@del_pattern` from `@array`, I loop through all the elements in `@del_pattern` and exclude them using grep.

```
## delete the patterns found in @del_pattern array
foreach $item (@del_pattern) {
    foreach $i (@array) {
        @$i = grep(!/$item/, @$i);
    }
}
```

However, I have been unable to remove `','` from `@array`. If I use `','` instead of `'\b,\b'` in `@del_pattern`, element `port_b,` gets removed from the `@array` as well, which is not an intended outcome. I am only interested in removing elements that contain only `','`.

Comment: Try using '^\,$' instead for removing the words having only , as the pattern you are using will remove all words having , anywhere in them.

Comment: So if you had `input_a` in `@array` should that get removed? In other words, do patterns need to match or to be equal?  For the comma you are saying that it should be equal -- "_that contain **only** `,`_" (my emphasis).

Comment: If I had `input_a` in `@array`, it shouldn't get removed. The patterns need to match

Comment: OK -- but not the comma?  With it, you remove an element only when it is exactly the comma?  If that is the case, it makes most sense to make that regex `/^,$/`, so that matching it means that it is equal.

Comment: Also, you should make your regex with `qr/.../` (not just single quotes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong regular expression. I updated the code and tried it and its working fine. PFB the update code:

```
my @del_pattern = ('input', 'output', 'wire', 'reg', '\b;\b', '^,$');

my @array = (['input', 'port_a', ','],
             ['output', '[31:0]', 'port_b,', 'port_c', ',']); 
## delete the patterns found in @del_pattern array
foreach my $item (@del_pattern) {
    foreach my $i (@array) {
        @$i = grep(!/$item/, @$i);
    }
}
```

The only change made is in the Regex '\b,\b' to '^,$'. I don't have  much info on \b but the regex I am suggesting is doing what you intend.

Comment: `^,$` will remove both `,` and `,␊`. `^,\z` is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

You want

```regex
^,\z
```

An explanation of what `\b` doesn't match at all follows.

---

```regex
\b
```

defines the boundary of a "word". It is equivalent to

```regex
(?<=\w)(?!\w) | (?<!\w)(?=\w)
```

so

```regex
\b,\b
```

is equivalent to

```regex
(?: (?<=\w)(?!\w) | (?<!\w)(?=\w) ) , (?: (?<=\w)(?!\w) | (?<!\w)(?=\w) )
```

Since comma is a non-word character, that simplifies to

```regex
(?<=\w),(?=\w)
```

So

```perl
'a,b' =~ /\b,\b/      # Match
','   =~ /\b,\b/      # No match
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but not very nice from the code.
This code snippet also removes the ','

```
 my $elm = [];

sub extract {
   my $elm = shift;

   foreach my $del (@del_pattern) {
      $elm =~ s/$del//g;
      if ( $elm ) {
         return $elm;
      }
   }
}


foreach my $item (@array) {
    foreach my $i (@$item) {
        my $extract = extract($i);
        if ($extract) {
           push(@$elm, $extract);
        }
    }
}

print Dumper($elm);
```

Why your `@array` has array? Why not one big array?

Comment: It is a nested array. The original array contains a list of lines, where a single line is an element. A line is then split with space as delimiter, which forms array within an array. I structured it such that it would be easier for me to trace if there is a bug